# Are leading periods really a part of written Spanish?

Tags: gramática, puntuación

I keep coming across passages like this in the Spanish (original) version of Don Quixote:

```
desfiguraban, dio una gran voz, diciendo:

. ¡Jesús! ¿Qué es lo que veo?

Y con el sobresalto se le cayó la vela de las manos; y,
```

(note the ". " after "deciendo:" and before "¡Jesús!")

Is it really so that there should be a period there? I doubt it, but I want to make sure.

grammar accent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That dot/period `.` means the dialogue start, now days is more common the use of `-` dash

> desfiguraban, dio una gran voz, diciendo: //narration
>
> . ¡Jesús! ¿Qué es lo que veo? //dialogue
>
> Y con el sobresalto se le cayó la vela de las manos; y, //narration

How I know is used now days is:

> desfiguraban, dio una gran voz, diciendo: //narration
>
> `-` ¡Jesús! ¿Qué es lo que veo? //dialogue
>
> Y con el sobresalto se le cayó la vela de las manos; y, //narration

Answer (score 2):

Not in the spanish grammar I know.  Maybe is an old spanish feature.  At present,  day, modern spanish do not use period inside a sentence,  we use only to finish a sentence.
You won't find this type of writing in any modern text.

Comment: En los libros se usa `-` guíon/dash para indicar donde empieza un diálogo